# Magento 2 : Date Custom Option Input on Cart Page

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.2, custom-options

I have created custom date option for products and its showing perfectly fine on product page. Now, I have to show that fields on cart page to its respective products. In short, users can update custom options on cart page as well.

[image: Fields on product page]

I want to show above fields on cart page and user should be able to update it.

[image: cart page]

Thanks in advance.